# Java - recursion countdown

Tags: java, recursion, countdown

I need to modify this code for counting from max to min so that it outputs the results from the method stej to the main method as a type String. The return of the stej method should then be printed in the main method. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int max = 0, min = 0;
    Scanner vhod = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("This program counts down from the inputed max and min.\n");
    System.out.print("Max must be greater or same as min!\n");
    System.out.print("Enter max: ");
    max = vhod.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter min: ");
    min = vhod.nextInt();

    if(max>=min) {
        stej(max, min);
    }
    else
        System.out.print("\nERROR: not valid max and/or min!");
}

static void stej(int max, int min) {    
    if(max==min) {
        System.out.print(min);
    }
    else {
        System.out.print(max + " ");
        stej(max-1, min);
    }
}
```

Comment: What should the result be? What do you want stej method to return on each iteration?

Comment: you are doing recursion in stej method(think it like a loop inside stej method starting from method open braces to close one), you can't go back everytime to main method and print the value in-between.

Answer (score 0):

I simplified the main to avoid typing but the code looks as follows :

```
public class Printing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int max = 10, min = 5;

        if (max >= min) {
            String result = stej(max, min);
            System.out.println("Result is :" + result);
        } else
            System.out.print("\nERROR: not valid max and/or min!");
    }

    static String stej(int max, int min) {
        if (max == min) {
            return String.valueOf(min);
        } else {
            return max + " " + stej(max - 1, min);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the quick reply :) will test it as soon as i get home :) will reply again